# Check if current time falls between a range, including "from 21:00 to 03:00"

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have two strings, `dateFrom` and `dateTo`, in format `NN:NN` and need to check if the current time falls between the range.

The problem is super-simple in theory, with the obvious:

```
  const d = new Date()
  const timeAsString = ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
```

Once they are strings, I can easily check whether `timeAsString > dateFrom && timeAsString < dateTo`

However, I would like to be able to ALSO set a valid interval as `timeFrom: "21:00"` and `timeTo: "0300"` -- and the check should return true for `01:00` (the rational: the "true" interval is between 9PM and 3AM, therefore 1AM is "good").

I could code it myself but I can already see gotchas that are going to byte me in the butt in 6 months time. This screams edge cases.

Is there a common, reliable pattern for this?

Comment: Don't roll your own code, you're not going to get it right (yay, timezones! time changes! calendar quirks! leap seconds! etc, etc). Use something like moment.js instead and ask it to do the work for you.

Comment: This is the only ONE line in a TINY script that has strict memory requirements. Believe me, I experience no joy in solving this kind of crap by hand.

Comment: what good is tiny if it's riddled with edge case bugs? Datetime logic is _the_ programming poster child for "for the love of everything good, _never_ do this yourself". Closely followed by text encoding.

Comment: Well, what good is "no edge cases, one established library, but  but won't fit the RAM"? Really...

Comment: As long as your `timeFrom` and `timeTo` values are considered to be in the same timezone as the computer on which you are doing the math, *and* you're willing to ignore daylight savings, you could use `inrange = (timeTo < timeFrom) ? (timeAsString <= timeTo || timeAsString >= timeFrom) : (timeAsString  >= timeFrom && timeAsString  <= timeTo)`